# Blogs Cannot Be Sorted Properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, loops

I am trying to build a blog, but now they are sorted first by category and then by id. Now, I have 2 loops, one for the categories and one for the blogs. The loop for the blogs is in the one of the categories.

I would like the blogs to be sorted just by id. So, whenever I publish a blog, I want it to appear on the first place no matter what category it is. Can you offer me a suggestion on how to modify my code:

```
    <?php 
            include_once("../forum/connect.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogcategories ORDER BY category DESC";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $blogs = "";
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
          $id = $row['id'];
          $category = $row['category'];

            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE blogcategories='".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC";
            $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0){

              while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){

                 $tid = $row2['id'];
                 $title = $row2['title'];
                 $image = $row2['image'];
                 $excerpt = $row2['excerpt'];                             
          $blogs .= "


            <hr>
                <h1>".$title."</h1>   
                <img src=".$image." alt=".$title.">
                <p class='description'>".$excerpt."</p>

       <!--------BUTTON READ MORE-------->

       <div id='hovers'>
        <a href='blog_view.php?cid=".$id."&tid=".$tid."' class='button' target='_blank'>
            <span class='contentbut'> Read More</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    ";         
        }
      }
    }

    echo $blogs; 
}
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put results to any other data structure and sort them. Using php standard lib.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Actually query results should be sorted. I think the problem arises when you use the results of first query to manipulate second one.

Comment: Yes. The problem arises from the two while loops but i cannot do it without them. What do you mean to echo the results. I think Echo $blogs is the result.

Comment: So it means simple blogs is not sorted.    $all_data = array();                                              $sql = "SELECT blah FROM blah";                 $result = mysql_query($sql);                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {                                       $all_data[] = $row; }  // $all_data is now a 2-D array with all your data. usort($all_data, "compare");

Comment: function compare($a, $b) {     // Assuming you're sorting on bar field     return strcmp($a['bar'], $b['bar']); }

Comment: So, my sql query should be this one $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE blogcategories='".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC"; do i have to just replace my second while loop with yours? What is bar in the compare function? Is it a column field in my sql table?

Comment: no. its an example. You have to define the compare function on element of blogs on which you want to sort. Yes bar is a column field.

Comment: I am a little confused.Can you offer me a solution using my code please? I will appreciate that a lot.

Comment: Give it a try by yourself. Read about usort and compare. Thanks.

Comment: I have been struggling with this yesterday all day and this morning as well. I am not sure if I can do it without further help. I will appreciate any further assistance from you. Thank you

Comment: Look it's simple you have the correct results in blogs but unordered?

Comment: I saw how compare and usort work, but cannot apply them to my code. I am very confused.  Can you offer me a suggestion on how to modify my code? I really need that finished. Thank you.

Comment: I have been trying a lot to sort the articles using your instructions, but I can't seem to be able to fix it. Can you try to modify my code?. Please.

Comment: The result is that first come all the articles from the first category, then all the articles from the second category, then all the articles from the third category, etc... And I want them to be sorted by date posted or by id.

Comment: I have been trying to fix the sorting of the blogs a lot, but with no success. Will you be able to help me sort the articles only by date.?

Comment: Okay here's the solution store the blogs again in a table in db. And then you can retrieve than from db here while retrieving you can sort. That's easy. You should be able to do this now.

Comment: You mean like this one?: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sf1g8d69pkng367/academy_second_best.php?dl=0            That is what I did before, but that way I will lose the categories and the link to the actual blog. There should be one main page with categories and blogs, one view_category page where we can see only blogs from a chosen category and one page for the actual blog.

Comment: You can save them this is not an issue. Bro stop looking for an exact solution. You just have to it conceptually. I can tell you ways. Not the exact solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But, the problem for me is how to save the categories. I think I already did what you meant in the dropbox link I sent, but there is no category there. That is my main problem.

Comment: Sorry can't help you more. Hope you get it.

Comment: Yes. I get what you mean. But that does not fix my problem. :(